# Jekyll - where is full-img class coming from?

Tags: jekyll

When I use image markdown like `![alt text](/assets/images/foo.png)`, for *some* images Jekyll is adding `class="full-img"`, making the image larger than it should be.

I observe the same behavior with both redcarpet and kramdown.

Why is that happening / how do I stop it?

Comment: Not sure that this class `.full-img` comes from jekyll or kramdown. Do you have some code available on github ?

Comment: I think it comes from the markdown processor - but I got same results with both redcarpet and kramdown.  Source for page in question on github is here:

https://github.com/wrschneider/wrschneider.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-08-10-combining-coverage-unit-functional.md

Comment: I noticed that both images with the issue are missing a newline directly after the image markdown. Try adding whitespace: MarkDown really loves its space.

Comment: nope, it's something about the image itself - if I replace the image URL for one of the impacted images with the image URL that worked OK, that other markup will work correctly too.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue.
In my case I use theme [kasper](https://github.com/rosario/kasper) .
I found that class `full-img` was not added by markdown engine, but the JavaScript code that author wrote in the `assets/js/index.js` file.
There's a function saying

```
    function updateImageWidth() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    contentWidth = $postContent.outerWidth(), // Width of the content
                    imageWidth = this.naturalWidth; // Original image resolution

                if (imageWidth >= contentWidth) {
                    $this.addClass('full-img');
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass('full-img');
                }
            }
```

After commenting every picture works fine as the original class.
That's my case.

Hopes that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  That at least gives me a clue what the trigger is and a hint for how to avoid it.